# SharePoint 2007, limit inserting item to list(calendar) if date\hour taken

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I'm trying to create a list in SharePoint 2007, in calendar view which allows people to ask for appointments. Is there is a way that people could only ask for appointment if the time is free(no one else asked for it before)?